# How to make pivot query in same table column based on onther column

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I have table [Application].[ApplicationDetails] where i have 3 columns in it

```
      ID   |  [QuestionId]   |   [Answer]
       1   |   106           |   YES I HAVE
       2   |   106           |   ONLY SIMAB HAVE
       3   |   107           |   ORANGES WERE SOUR
       4   |   107           |   GRAPES SOUR
       5   |   108           |   ALEIN CENTER 
       6   |   106           |   no one
```

I want a pivot query to display my data of answer againt question ID like

```
     QuestionId
Answers
```

example

```
  106              108 
  YES I HAVE       ALEIN CENTER
  ONLY SIMAB HAVE
```

and go on here what I am trying todo

```
      WITH cte AS (
           SELECT [QuestionId] as [Quest],
             [Answer] as [Answer] 

      FROM  [Application].[ApplicationDetails]

      )

                SELECT [Answer] ,[Quest]
                FROM
                (
                SELECT [Quest]  , [Answer]

                FROM cte
                          ) d
                pivot
                (
                [Answer]  in [Quest]
      ) piv
        ORDER BY [Quest];
```

but this not working incorrect keyword in

Comment: SQL SERVER i am using

Comment: you cannot have them on same row when they dont have same id

Comment: question id 106 answers below 106 and 107 answers below 107

Comment: Question id as column and answer as row

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is short `Dynamic Pivot` Way :

```
DECLARE @Str NVARCHAR(MAX);
DECLARE @Str2 NVARCHAR(MAX);
SELECT @Str = STUFF(
                   (
                       SELECT DISTINCT
                              ','+QUOTENAME(QuestionID)
                       FROM <table_name> FOR XML PATH('')
                   ), 1, 1, '');

                  -- PRINT @Str

SET @str2 = N'select * from (
   select QuestionID,Answer,ROW_NUMBER() over(PARTITION by QuestionID order by answer) as rn
   from <table_name>
   )x
   PIVOT 
   (Max(Answer) FOR QuestionID in ('+@Str+')
   ) as p';
--PRINT @Str2;
EXEC (@Str2);
```

Result :

```
rn  106             107                 108
1   YES I HAVE      GRAPES SOUR         ALEIN CENTER    
2   no one          ORANGES WERE SOUR   NULL
3   ONLY SIMAB HAVE NULL                NULL
```

Answer (score 0):

This should give you the desired results.

```
SELECT [106], [107]
FROM (
    SELECT QuestionId, Answer, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY QuestionId ORDER BY Answer) r
    FROM [dbo].[ApplicationDetails]
) t
PIVOT(MAX(Answer) FOR QuestionId IN ([106], [107])) AS p
```

**EDITED (Dynamic SQL)**

```
DECLARE @QuestionIds VARCHAR(MAX), @Query VARCHAR(MAX);

WITH DistinctResults AS (
    SELECT DISTINCT '[' + CAST(QuestionId AS VARCHAR) + ']' QuestionId FROM [ApplicationDetails]
)
SELECT @QuestionIds = (SELECT QuestionId + ', ' AS 'data()'  FROM DistinctResults FOR XML PATH(''));


SELECT @QuestionIds = STUFF(@QuestionIds, LEN(@QuestionIds), 1, '')

SELECT @Query = 
N'SELECT ' + @QuestionIds + '
FROM (
    SELECT QuestionId, Answer, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY QuestionId ORDER BY Answer) r
    FROM [dbo].[ApplicationDetails]
) t
PIVOT(MAX(Answer) FOR QuestionId IN (' + @QuestionIds + ')) AS p';

EXEC (@Query)
```

Comment: its not only 2 id's 106 or 107 there are large data so we should try for all ids

Comment: Then you should use a dynamic sql query.

Comment: how it should be can you help me

Comment: some this like that `SELECT  (select CAST([QuestionId] AS INT)  FROM [Application].[ApplicationDetails] )  as test  
FROM (
    SELECT [QuestionId], Answer, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY QuestionId ORDER BY Answer) r
    FROM [Application].[ApplicationDetails]
) t
PIVOT(MAX(Answer) FOR QuestionId IN (  test   )) AS p`

Comment: but give error _Error converting data type nvarchar to int.
Msg 473, Level 16, State 1, Line 8
The incorrect value "test" is supplied in the PIVOT operator._

Comment: Modified the answer with dynamic SQL.

Answer (score 0):

This here will give you your desired result however when you have IDs in your select there will be null values where your questionid doesnt match the text.

```
DECLARE @myt TABLE (
 ID int, QuestionID int, Answer nvarchar(50)
  )

  insert into @myt
  values 

   (1,   106,'YES I HAVE'),
   (2,   106,'ONLY SIMAB HAVE'),
   (3,   107,'ORANGES WERE SOUR'),
   (4,   107,'GRAPES SOUR'),
   (5,   108,'ALEIN CENTER'),
   (6,   106,'no one')



   select [106],[107],[108]
   from @myt
   PIVOT 
   (Max(Answer) FOR QUESTIONID in ([106],[107],[108])
   ) as p;
```

And if you want it on same rows with new IDs

```
DECLARE @myt TABLE (
 ID int, QuestionID int, Answer nvarchar(50)
 )

   insert into @myt
 values 

   (1,   106,'YES I HAVE'),
   (2,   106,'ONLY SIMAB HAVE'),
   (3,   107,'ORANGES WERE SOUR'),
   (4,   107,'GRAPES SOUR'),
   (5,   108,'ALEIN CENTER'),
   (6,   106,'no one')



  select * from (
   select QuestionID,Answer,ROW_NUMBER() over(PARTITION by QuestionID order by answer) as rn
   from @myt
   )x
   PIVOT 
   (Max(Answer) FOR QuestionID in ([106],[107],[108])
   ) as p
```

**EDIT UPDATE WITH DYNAMIC SQL**

```
/*CREATE TABLE*/


CREATE TABLE Dbo.TESTQUESTION (
ID int, QuestionID int, Answer nvarchar(50)
 )

 insert into dbo.TESTQUESTION
 values 

(1,   106,'YES I HAVE'),
(2,   106,'ONLY SIMAB HAVE'),
(3,   107,'ORANGES WERE SOUR'),
(4,   107,'GRAPES SOUR'),
(5,   108,'ALEIN CENTER'),
(6,   106,'no one')




  declare @gruppe nvarchar(max)
  declare @gruppeSql nvarchar(max)
  declare @SQL nvarchar(max)
  DECLARE myCustomers CURSOR FOR
  select distinct   QuestionID from dbo.TESTQUESTION 
  set @gruppeSql = ''
  OPEN myCustomers
   FETCH NEXT FROM myCustomers INTO @gruppe
  IF (@@FETCH_STATUS>=0)
  BEGIN
  SET @gruppeSql = @gruppeSql +'[' +@gruppe+']'
  FETCH NEXT FROM myCustomers INTO @gruppe
   END
   WHILE (@@FETCH_STATUS<>-1)
   BEGIN
   IF (@@FETCH_STATUS<>-2)

   SET @gruppeSql = @gruppeSql  + ',[' +@gruppe+']'
   FETCH NEXT FROM myCustomers INTO @gruppe
   END
   CLOSE myCustomers
   DEALLOCATE myCustomers 

  SET @gruppeSql = replace(@gruppesql,'''','')
  select @gruppeSql
   SET @SQL = '
    select * from (
   select QuestionID,Answer,ROW_NUMBER() over(PARTITION by QuestionID order 
 by answer) as rn
   from dbo.TESTQUESTION
   )x
   PIVOT 
   (Max(Answer) FOR QuestionID in ('+@gruppesql+') 
   ) as p'


  exec(@sql)
```

**Result with dynamic query and self made IDs**
[image]

Comment: I told the data is example i have large data these are hard coded ids but i need effective solution not hardcoded as data is large

Comment: like get id first `SELECT  (select CAST([QuestionId] AS INT)  FROM [Application].[ApplicationDetails] )  as test  `

Comment: Well thats not your asking for in your questions. If you wanna solve it on multple values then you should make your column selection dynamic

Answer (score 0):

Just Add your Required questionId's you will get the result based on questionId's

Sample Data creation

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#t') IS NOT NULL
DROP TABLE #t;

IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#Result') IS NOT NULL
DROP TABLE #Result;

GO

;With cte(ID,[QuestionId],[Answer])
AS
(
SELECT 1,106,'YES I HAVE'       UNION ALL
SELECT 2,106,'ONLY SIMAB HAVE'  UNION ALL
SELECT 3,107,'ORANGES WERE SOUR'UNION ALL
SELECT 4,107,'GRAPES SOUR'      UNION ALL
SELECT 5,108,'ALEIN CENTER'     UNION ALL
SELECT 6,106,'no one'
)
SELECT *  INTO #t FROM cte
```

Add Required QuestionId's in below variable

```
DECLARE @QuestinID VARCHAR(100)='106,107,108'-- Add Required QuestionId's

DECLARE @GetQuestion TABLE (QuestionID VARCHAR(100))
    INSERT INTO @GetQuestion
    SELECT @QuestinID


    SELECT * INTO #Result 
    FROM #t WHERE QuestionID IN(SELECT CAST(Split.a.value('.','nvarchar(1000)') AS INT) AS QuestionID  FROM
    (
    SELECT 
    CAST('<S>'+REPLACE(QuestionID,',','</S><S>')+'</S>' AS XML ) AS QuestionID 
    FROM @GetQuestion 
    )AS A
    CROSS APPLY QuestionID.nodes('S') AS Split(a))
    ORDER BY QuestionID


    DECLARE @Sql nvarchar(max),@DyColm nvarchar(max)

    SELECT @DyColm=STUFF((SELECT DISTINCT ', '+ QUOTENAME(CAST(QuestionID AS VARCHAR(10))) FROM #Result FOR XML PATH ('')),1,2,'')



    SET @Sql='
    SELECT '+@DyColm+' FROm
    (
    SELECT * FRom #Result
    )AS Src
     PIVOT
     (
     MAX([Answer]) FOR QuestionID IN ('+@DyColm+')
     )AS Pvt
     '

     PRINT @Sql
     EXEC(@Sql)
     SET NOCOUNT OFF
```